# SphinxQL Error on Show Meta;

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

As far as I know I can run

`Show Meta;`

After doing a SphinxQL search to see what Sphinx is actually searching for. 
 However I keep getting

`sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected SUBKEY, expecting $end near '.PROFILING GROUP BY QUERY_ID'`

Yet my searches seem to work fine. Is my syntax wrong or is there something in my index itself I should explore or look for?

Comment: Can you show the full query you run when you get this error? Do you use any ORM which can issue queries like "... .PROFILING GROUP BY QUERY_ID" hiding it from you?

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev It is really any query even a basic `Select * from IndexA` (which runs fine) and then `Show Meta`'

Comment: What mysql client are you using? Navicat?

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev Yes Navicat for MySql. Never had an issue before

Comment: Sphinx is not compatible with Navicat. Either use another client or configure Navicat so it doesn't do profiling, i.e. doesn't issue query "... PROFILING GROUP BY QUERY_ID" .

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev I have used navicat successfully in the past with `Show Meta` which made me believe I broke something in the index which, while not catastrophic since it searches, needed to be looked intio.

Comment: it's strange it worked previously and doesn't work now. I've just tried Navicat for Mac with Manticoresearch v2.6.1 (fork of Sphinx) and all worked fine. I do "select * from idx; show meta" in Navicat and get the results for both in "Result 1" and "Result 2" tabs, the "syntax error" exists, but I can see it only in Manticoresearch query log, no signs of that in Navicat. I would suggest to try to upgrade Navicat, but since you say it was working there before it will probably not help.

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev I was thinking the same thing in fact; that if it used to work and does not it is because of their newer software not their older. I can see if I can get 11.x and try that. Will report back.

Answer (score 0):

In editions past 11 in Navicat, go to View Menu and deselect 'Show Profile and Status'